# how can we setup exe in shared hosting?

Tags: c#, hosting

**Hi,
I have a shared hosting and i want to place one exe on root of the directory and 

want to run that exe once in a day .

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Or 

should we need to buy dedicated hosting ?

Please help!!**

Comment: Can you clarify what type of program it is, or at least why you'd need hosting for a simple exe?  And why the *root* directory, and not just your user directory?  It isn't clear in your question *why* you'd even need hosting to begin with.  If your question is really just "how do I run an arbitrary program once a day", then see Chris's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally not with shared hosting.

If you really want to execute a program on a schedule on your web server, at a minimum you're going to need some kind of hosting where you have enough control over the OS to access its task scheduling mechanism.

This kind of control is generally available at minimum with a VPS (Virtual Private Server) or shell account, depending on platform.

Comment: If the OP's requirements are accurate your answer is correct, but I'm not sure there's enough information in the question to justify this answer.  "Spend money repeatedly on a service" is a pretty hefty suggestion.  I know the OP already jumped to that conclusion, but I'm not sure they are even sure about their requirements.  They might not need hosting at all, and they might be able to get away with a shell account and a cron job (for example)

Comment: Hopefully my updated answer falls more in line with what you thought I should have said :-)

Comment: +1 for the edit.  I wouldn't care, but this guy seems to be ready to take business advice from strangers over the net :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Windows Task Scheduler` to run programs once a day such as `bat` files or scripts.